# Is there anyway to know whether an entry in Linux symbol table is a function or a variable?

Tags: c, linux, symbols

The Linux command `nm` can list a symbol table. However I do not know the type of a symbol inside it.

The `nm` command does not tell whether a symbol is a function or a global valuable.

Currently I am building a symbol table to enable module support in a firmware but if I do not know whether a symbol denotes a function or valuable, I cannot initialize correctly.

For example, assume my symbol table structure is:

```
struct symtab { 
  const char *name; 
  void *addr; 
  int isfunc; 
};
```

Then I want to added a entry about "printk". I know printk is a function, so the entry is { "printk", printk, 1}. However if I do not know that and treat `printk` as a variable, there comes the problem. The entry { "printk", &printk, 0 } will cause an error.

I investigated the code of Grub 2.00, and I found that some tags like "EXPORT_FUNC" or "EXPORT_VAR" are used in the function prototypes (like `void EXPORT_FUNC (usb_open) (void)`) so that some scripts can use these tags to generate a correct symbol table.

My problem is that my current project does not have these tags.

Is there a method to know whether a symbol is a function or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Linux, so your object files are ELF format, right? Is so, use `objdump -t`, so you can see the flags and the section each symbol is in. The output is described in [`man 1 objdump`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) man page, under `-t` option, about three quarters down.

Consider, for example, this file:

```
extern int reference;

int initialized_variable = 1;

static int static_initialized_variable = 2;

const int const_variable = 3;

static const int static_const_variable = 4;

int variable;

static int static_variable;

int function(void)
{
    return 5;
}

static int static_function(void)
{
    return 6;
}
```

Compiled using `gcc -c example.c` using gcc-4.6.3 on x86-64, `objdump -t example.o` yields

```
example.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 example.c
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 l    d  .data  0000000000000000 .data
0000000000000000 l    d  .bss   0000000000000000 .bss
0000000000000004 l     O .data  0000000000000004 static_initialized_variable
0000000000000000 l    d  .rodata    0000000000000000 .rodata
0000000000000004 l     O .rodata    0000000000000004 static_const_variable
0000000000000000 l     O .bss   0000000000000004 static_variable
000000000000000b l     F .text  000000000000000b static_function
0000000000000000 l    d  .note.GNU-stack    0000000000000000 .note.GNU-stack
0000000000000000 l    d  .eh_frame  0000000000000000 .eh_frame
0000000000000000 l    d  .comment   0000000000000000 .comment
0000000000000000 g     O .data  0000000000000004 initialized_variable
0000000000000000 g     O .rodata    0000000000000004 const_variable
0000000000000004       O *COM*  0000000000000004 variable
0000000000000000 g     F .text  000000000000000b function
```

The second column is actually fixed-width, seven flag characters:

```
                 ^^^^^^^
```

The flag characters are described in the [objdump man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/objdump.1.html) as follows:

```
The flag characters are divided into 7 groups as follows:

       "l"
       "g"
       "u"
       "!" The symbol is a local (l), global (g), unique global (u),
           neither global nor local (a space) or both global and local
           (!).  A symbol can be neither local or global for a variety
           of reasons, e.g., because it is used for debugging, but it is
           probably an indication of a bug if it is ever both local and
           global.  Unique global symbols are a GNU extension to the
           standard set of ELF symbol bindings.  For such a symbol the
           dynamic linker will make sure that in the entire process
           there is just one symbol with this name and type in use.

       "w" The symbol is weak (w) or strong (a space).

       "C" The symbol denotes a constructor (C) or an ordinary symbol (a
           space).

       "W" The symbol is a warning (W) or a normal symbol (a space).  A
           warning symbol's name is a message to be displayed if the
           symbol following the warning symbol is ever referenced.

       "I"
       "i" The symbol is an indirect reference to another symbol (I), a
           function to be evaluated during reloc processing (i) or a
           normal symbol (a space).

       "d"
       "D" The symbol is a debugging symbol (d) or a dynamic symbol (D)
           or a normal symbol (a space).

       "F"
       "f"
       "O" The symbol is the name of a function (F) or a file (f) or an
           object (O) or just a normal symbol (a space).
```

You can either rely on the flags, or you can infer the symbol type from the fact that code normally resides in a `.text` section, read-only data in a `.rodata` section, initialized data in a `.data` section, and uninitialized data in a `.bss` section. Note that using GCC extensions, the section name may get a suffix; for example, a function that is to be executed automatically at startup (`__attribute__((constructor))`), will usually end up in a `.text.startup` section. So, do a prefix match on the section name, instead of exact match.

---

For a custom firmware, there are several approaches you can use to provide module support. If you use ELF format for the firmware binaries, you can parse the above information directly. For example, the Linux kernel uses this approach. (For fun, try `objdump -t` on the kernel `.ko` modules in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/`.)

For a microcontroller, ELF support is overkill. You'd still need a dynamic linker (and a simpler than ELF format for your firmware binaries) if you want your firmware to be able to load modules on demand. The bottleneck is usually the amount of RAM available. If you have lots, and you need your firmware to be able to load new modules at runtime, go with ELF.

It is often more efficient to be able to *link* different modules (and perhaps even static configuration data) together on a workstation, to "construct" a complete new firmware image, and then load that blob to the device. (The blob is often a memory image with CRC checks, then.) For this, a GUI application written in C, C++, or even in a higher-level portable language like Python (which has many ELF modules you could use for this) to do it in a portable fashion; a "configurator" application, if you will. Developers would use normal toolchains to produce ELF-format binary modules, which the end users can combine in the configurator application to produce a firmware image.

Answer (score 0):

Use readelf utility to get all the details about the object file. For more info on readelf `man readelf` it gives all the details about a symbol in symbol table.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This command also works:
    readelf -s elf-file(s)